# Testing of IOS App on a Windows PC

Tags: emulators

I am tasked with testing an IOS application...I have an iPad & and iPhone to test on but am looking for an application that will let me test on my windows machine, possibly using an emulator.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There are few labs right now that you can choose from if you don't have access to real iOS devices.

Few of them:

```
TestDroid
Sauce labs
Perfecto Mobile
Kobiton
Amazon AWS Device farm
Google FireBase
Xamarin Test Cloud
Experitest
pCloudy
BrowserStack
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there aren't too many options to test Apple products on non-Apple hardware.  It is actually against their terms of service.

Off the top of my head, you can illegally make a hackentosh, or get a hackentosh virtual machine.  This probably won't be good if you are doing this as part of an actual job.  Additionally, hackentoshes are notoriously buggy.  So testing on them probably won't be reliable.

Or you can rent an actual remote apple computer and vnc or remote desktop in. [MacInCloud](https://www.macincloud.com/)

Pretty much every company I have worked for has used actual mac devices: mac mini, iphone, ipad to run their testing or CI.

Answer (score 0):

There are different 'cloud' solutions that offer iOS devices to test on. See some mentioned [here](https://adtmag.com/blogs/dev-watch/2017/05/device-clouds.aspx).

I don't know where that iOS application is supposed to work on, but having 1 iPhone and 1 iPad seems a bit minimalistic. You probably have to test on at least the latest and greatest and previous iOS version to name one. And the most used devices. See for instance numbers for [versions](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/) (the newest iOS12 is not mentioned ;-)) and [devices](https://www.statista.com/statistics/804398/us-iphone-sales-by-model/).

As Apple has a closed ecosystem, trying to get it to work outside it (e.g. on Windows) is a waste of time. 
The best solution would be to have a chat with your manager and get yourself a Mac to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Most useful are of course real devices. You need one iPhone X variant. Best is an iPhone XR - cheapest and it can run in "Zoom" mode which means you can change it to behave like an iPhone X or XS. iPhone X is needed because the notch, rounded corners etc. may cause UI problems.

You need a large iPhone - an old iPhone 6+ will do fine. Again, it supports zoom mode so you can change it to iPhone 6 behaviour. If the app runs fine on this, it should run fine on iPhone 7 and 8 as well.

You need a small iPhone - an old iPhone 5s will do fine. Your company then needs to decide which OS they support and whether they support 32 bit devices. If they require iOS 10 and 64 bit then you are fine with iPhones.

I would get the latest version of the 9.7 iPad because it has software features that older ones don't have, creating some UI challenges. You can hope and pray that the software runs fine on iPad Pros. You *should* have an iPad Pro but if money is really, really tight go without it.

But the best and cheapest would be getting a modern used Mac, best would be an iMac 27" Retina, and ask your developers to install Xcode for you. Then you can emulate *every* device. AND you can emulate every operating system version. I managed to get a used one for £1,000. But ask your developers about it. (And if your developers are far away, it may be impossible). The big screen is needed so you can emulate all the devices in full resolution.